# Compare two lists and give 1 and 0 using if command

Tags: list-manipulation

There are two lists{2,5,9,...} and {natural numbers}. I need to compare it with natural numbers and get a list with 0 and 1 if the number is present in the list, to get {0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,..}

Comment: Question is not clear. Can you give the short list you have and desired output?

Comment: All natural numbers?

Comment: @Kuba:  Are you saying that your computer doesn't have $\aleph_0$ bytes of memory?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert :) I was concerned about the case where the first list contains integers outside of range of the second one.

Answer (score 18):

Use [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html).

```
SparseArray[List /@ {2, 5, 9} -> 1] // Normal
(* {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1} *)
```

Comment: This is brilliant! I would not have thought of that.

Answer (score 7):

```
list = {2,5,9,20};
res = ConstantArray[0, Last[list]] (* replace Last by Max if list is not ordered *)
res[[list]] = 1;
res
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
> ```

Comment: You could also use `ReplacePart`, to avoid mutating data. But your approach is probably shorter.

Answer (score 5):

How about this? A little verbose...

```
list = {2, 5, 9, 10, 119};
checklist[list_List] := Boole /@ (MemberQ[list, #] & /@ Range[Max[list]])
checklist@list
```

> {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>   0, 0, 0, 1}

**Edit:**

Another one, just for fun:

```
CoefficientList[Plus @@ ((x^#) & /@ list), x]
```

Comment: That last one is just silly.  Kudos.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {2, 5, 9};
checklist = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 10]
(*{9, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 4}*)

Map[(If[MemberQ[list, #], 1, 0]) &, checklist]
(*{1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {2, 5, 9};
```

Using `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[Array[0 &, Max@#], List /@ # -> 1] &@list

(*{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}*)
```

Or an equivalent way (Thanks to @Syed):

```
ReplacePart[Table[0, Max[list]], Thread[list -> 1]]

(*{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}*)
```

Comment: Also: `ReplacePart[Table[0, Max[list]], Thread[list -> 1]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {2, 5, 9, 10};
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
Unitize @ SubsetMap[list &, Table[0, Max @ list], list]
```

{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}

Answer (score 0):

**Using `IntegerDigits`:**

```
list = {2, 5, 9, 10};

2^(Max@list - list) // Total // IntegerDigits[#, 2, Max@list] &
```

> {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}